# Authenticated pakage virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, lxterminal

i am trying to install virtualbox in ubuntu on the terminal:

```
varel@varel-Pc:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
[sudo] password for varel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
dkms libgsoap4 libqt4-opengl libvncserver0 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-   qt
Suggested packages:
debhelper libvncserver0-dbg virtualbox-guest-additions-iso vde2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dkms libgsoap4 libqt4-opengl libvncserver0 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 21,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 87,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
libgsoap4
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] N
E: Some packages could not be authenticated
varel@varel-Pc:~$
```

is the authenticated libgsoap4 can break my computer???

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libgsoap4`

Comment: could also be a corrupted `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Release.gpg `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Install the most recent stable version of VirtualBox (version 5).

**First remove the old VirtualBox version before installing VirtualBox-5!**

1. Open a terminal and execute : → `sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"`
2. Check carefully what will be removed before you confirm.
3. Update the software repositories → `sudo apt-get update`
4. Clean up → `sudo apt-get autoremove | sudo apt-get autoclean | sudo apt-get clean`

**Install the most recent version**

1. Download and register the ORACLE public key:

   ```
    wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
2. Add the VirtualBox repository to the sources list:

   ```
    echo "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-vbox.list
   ```
3. Update the software repositories again:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install VirtualBox:

   ```
    sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5
   ```
5. In case you use another version of Ubuntu - replace "vivid" with the version you are running.
6. Download the matching extension pack from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
7. To add the guest additions open virtualbox → <kbd>Preferences</kbd>: add the extension pack manually.

**Note for other users reading this answer, in case they use another Ubuntu edition as 15.04 :**

You have to replace `vivid` with the Ubuntu edition you are using when adding the repository !

As of Ubuntu 16.04 the ORACLE public key to download and register has  changed :

`oracle_vbox.asc` has to be replaced with `oracle_vbox_2016.asc` !

Answer (score 2):

It could be a corrupted apt file list. This would help fix that ...

```
sudo tar cvfz /tmp/backup.lists.tar.gz /var/lib/apt/lists*
sudo rm -frv /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -pv /var/lib/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-key update
```

1st one makes a backup of the current files just in case.

Mind though: I have not found a method to decide IF it is a corrupt file list besides actually doing the above. The backup is not needed btw, added myself.